# Correlate all pairs of values in a time series in r

Tags: r, matrix, time-series, correlation

I'm trying to correlate timeseries data within site pairs. I'm working with a data set that looks like this:

A= Site, B= Year and C= Abundance:

```
         A    B    C
 [1,]    1 2002   21
 [2,]    1 2004   25
 [3,]    1 2005   26
 [4,]    2 3003   24
 [5,]    2 2004   20
 [6,]    2 2005   20
 [7,]    3 2002   21
 [8,]    3 2003   22
 [9,]    3 2004   23
[10,]    3 2005   25
```

I want to split the data by column A to test correlation between each site pair (site 1 with 2 and 3, site 2 with 1 and 3 etc.)

I've tried:
mydata.cor = cor(dat, method = c("spearman"))

But this just correlates the columns:

```
           A          B          C
A  1.0000000 -0.1287697 -0.1684834
B -0.1287697  1.0000000  0.4151682
C -0.1684834  0.4151682  1.0000000
```

Is there a way specify grouping values, in this case site category?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

one way to do it would be to transform your data to wide format
and then use `cor()` as you intended to (on the relevant columns).

Here's my reproducible code, I assumed that the 3003 in line 4 was a typo ...

```
library(data.table)

mat <- matrix(c(
    1, 2002,   21,
    1, 2004,   25,
    1, 2005,   26,
    2, 2003,   24,
    2, 2004,   20,
    2, 2005,   20,
    3, 2002,   21,
    3, 2003,   22,
    3, 2004,   23,
    3, 2005,   25),10,3,byrow = TRUE)

DT <- data.table(mat)
names(DT) <- c("A","B","C")

DT_wide <- dcast(DT, B~A)
cor(DT_wide[,-1], method="spearman", use="pairwise.complete.obs")
```